# problem with webcam feed buffer in JavaScript (p5js)

Tags: javascript, buffer, p5.js, webcam

so in my code i'm storing the webcam feed in a buffer and use it later, the code is somehow structcerd to overlay the video feed on some text, but i can't get the webcam feed working in large resolutions, it just stays at a certain weird size no matter what i do. and if i multiply the video size, it will mess up the ratio in devices other than me

this is the setup bit that has the buffer and all

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight);
  pg = createGraphics(displayWidth, displayHeight);  

  textSize(24);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

  video = createCapture(VIDEO);
  video.size(displayWidth*2, displayHeight*2);
  video.hide();

  
  const faceOptions = {
    withLandmarks: true,
    withExpressions: true,
    withDescriptors: true,
    minConfidence: 0.5
  };

  faceapi = ml5.faceApi(video, faceOptions, faceReady);
}

function faceReady() {
  faceapi.detect(gotFaces);  // Start detecting faces
}
```

and this is the part of a function that uses the buffer

```
function displayVideoText() {
  pg.clear();
  pg.fill(255); 

  let y = 20;  
  dialoguesToDisplay.forEach(dialogue => {
    pg.text(dialogue, 0, y);
    y += 15;  
  });

  video.loadPixels();
  pg.loadPixels();
  loadPixels();

  for (let i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 4) {
    if (pg.pixels[i + 3] !== 0) {  
      pixels[i] = video.pixels[i];
      pixels[i + 1] = video.pixels[i + 1];
      pixels[i + 2] = video.pixels[i + 2];
      pixels[i + 3] = video.pixels[i + 3];
    }
  }

  updatePixels();
}
```

you see the first picture is from my laptop which the code works fine, second is my phone which i only have wrong aspect ratio, and third is my freinds phone which is completley messed up .[Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EFeE.png) [MyPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n48Oy.png) [Friend'sPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfXLN.jpg)

i tried changing the buffer size and video size, didn't help, also i get this error in console :
error: Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true.
And it points out to this part of core p5js library :
COde: var imageData = this.drawingContext.getImageData(0, 0, w, h); // @todo this should actually set pixels per object, so diff buffers can // have diff pixel arrays.